# SSL handshake 20s delay to complete process

Tags: ssl

We are experiencing a delay when accessing https:// connection to our server.
There is a delay around the 20s to display the content of the page which was trace to SSL handshake process

Using

```
strace -o /tmp/curl.trace.log -f -tt curl -kvv --trace-time https://10.20.23.7:
```

We trace this to

```
91445 09:22:03.711590 getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9070), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.20.23.7")}, [16]) = 0

91445 09:22:03.773153 sendto(3, "\26\3\1\0\220\1\0\0\214\3\3\332\3n\204\371\2472v\341E[\2247=2;\336\214\266}\4"..., 149, 0, NULL, 0) = 149

91445 09:22:03.773267 recvfrom(3, 0x1c2b258, 5, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
91445 09:22:03.773315 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
91445 09:22:08.778047 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
91445 09:22:13.783040 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
91445 09:22:18.787090 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
91445 09:22:20.183606 recvfrom(3, "\26\3\3\n\264", 5, 0, NULL, NULL) = 5
91445 09:22:20.183724 recvfrom(3, "\2\0\0M\3\3]\312\300\34\367\363\256%V\25s)\tSVX\317*\272=\205(\311\1<\345"..., 2740, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2740
91445 09:22:20.184242 fcntl(4, F_SETLK, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=1073741824, len=1}) = 0
```

As I understand recvfrom is not able to read request which was `sendto(..)`

What mean line sendto, where request was sendto?

```
91445 09:22:03.773153 sendto(3, "\26\3\1\0\220\1\0\0\214\3\3\332\3n\204\371\2472v\341E[\2247=2;\336\214\266}\4"..., 149, 0, NULL, 0) = 149
```

Thank you for info.

Comment: The delay may be caused by an OCSP checking (running into a time-out) on client and/or server side.

Comment: @Robert: In order to timeout on OCSP checking on the client side the client would have to get the server certificate first. But the handshake hangs after sending the ClientHello and before getting the server certificate.

Comment: The problem is not on the client side but the server is not responding fast enough from the perspective of the client. Since nothing is known about the server and its configuration nor about any network architecture (which might contain firewalls delaying traffic) no further help can be provided currently.

Comment: Thank you for updates

trace log I collect from configuration
Server  - firewall - client

Similar situation I expirence when I am doing curl on this same server where web server is running ( curl -kvv https://localhost )
The server is running Solaris, web application is using apache tomee